# SPH simulations

Tags: software

Are there any simulations that can be obtained that use smooth particle hydrodynamics and can be configured to include different initial conditions? I wish to simulate planetary collisions and their impact. I wish to *exactly replicate* the following link.

---

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fwl_JBQtH9o

---

Comment: It would be awesome if you could tell a bit more precisely, what do you really wish for. There are plenty of algorithms, inlcuding SPH and its variations, many codes written and many nice outputs produced, planetary collisions included.

Comment: The algorithm that I am looking for should be able to simulate collisions like the following link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fwl_JBQtH9o

Comment: I am trying to exactly duplicate the code used for that YouTube link.

Comment: Could you find Canup's SPH code? I'm a PhD Brazilian student and I'm looking for a code like you.. Thanks =)

Comment: @AndreAmarante, unfortunately, I was unable to find Canup's code. Other  SPH codes did provide a lot of insight into how to figure it out, so I would recommend checking those out. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend MPA Garching's [Gadget](http://www.mpa-garching.mpg.de/gadget/) code for cosmological simulations of structure formation. It's primarily gravitational, but I do believe you can include gas effects as well:

> GADGET computes gravitational forces with a hierarchical tree algorithm (optionally in combination with a particle-mesh scheme for long-range gravitational forces) and represents fluids by means of smoothed particle hydrodynamics (SPH). The code can be used for studies of isolated systems, or for simulations that include the cosmological expansion of space, both with or without periodic boundary conditions. In all these types of simulations, GADGET follows the evolution of a self-gravitating collisionless N-body system, and allows gas dynamics to be optionally included. Both the force computation and the time stepping of GADGET are fully adaptive, with a dynamic range which is, in principle, unlimited.

I don't know if this is what is commonly used for tasks such as yours, but it might be a place to start looking.

Comment: Thanks :) it is a good headstart. I wish to exactly simulate https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fwl_JBQtH9o

Comment: There many different SPH codes around the astronomy community (I have one myself), but AFAIK none except gadget are publicly available for download (simply because these codes are very specific and easy to break if you don't know what you're doing). The problem with gadget is that it implements an out-of-date SPH algorithm (>10 years old) and was never really meant for planet collisions (I bet you would need a particular equation of state for planet collisions).

Comment: Ah yes. I plan to use the ANEOS analytical equations of state.

Comment: I would like a simulation with a more updated version of the SPH algorithm, no problem if I have to purchase it :) Any suggestions?

Comment: @Walter: there are many other good publically available SPH codes. Check any recent review on SPH, e.g. Springel, Price or Rosswog.

Comment: Will definitely have a look. Thanks to all for their comments.